# Object #<Object> has no method 'draggable'

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am writing a constructor for postcards. On this constructor I have to be able to add texts and inputs for editing these texts. And these texts are draggable.
I have function for appending texts and inputs to correct places:

```
function addTextWithControls(maxId, posX, posY, text, fontstyles) {                   
        var idForAdding = parseInt(maxId);  
        idForAdding++; //get id for appending elements
        $('#inputsBox').append('<div class="inputBox"><input type="text" name="text'+idForAdding+'" id="text'+idForAdding+'Inp" placeholder="Введите текст" value="'+text+'" onkeyup="changeText('+idForAdding+');" data-type="textInput" data-id="'+idForAdding+'"/><span id="text'+idForAdding+'Remover" data-type="remover" class="textRemover" data-id="'+idForAdding+'"></span><div class="cleaner"></div></div>');

        $('div.finishedPic').append('<span id="text'+idForAdding+'Span" data-type="textOnPic" style="left: '+posX+'px; top:'+posY+'px; '+fontstyles+'" data-id="'+idForAdding+'">'+text+'</span>');

         $(function() {        
            //calling .draggable for new appended element
            $( "div.finishedPic span" ).draggable({ containment: "parent" , 
                drag: function(){
                    console.log('.');                        
                },
            });
            //calling .sortable for new appended element
            $( "#inputsBox" ).sortable({
                placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
                update: function(){
                    setZindexes(); 
                }
            });
            $( "#inputsBox" ).disableSelection();
                 
        });
         
    }
```

And I have two ways for calling this addTextWithControls() function:
**First way:**
While loading document I call initCard() function:

```
     $(document).ready(function(){
        initCard();
     });
```

So the initCard() function contains addTextWithControls() function:

```
 function initCard(json) {
        $('div.finishedPic img').attr('src', json.image);  //set background image                    
        $.each(json.texts, function() { //parse json for getting information
            var styles = '';                
            var obj = this.fontstyles;               
            forEach(obj, function(key, value){
                styles += key+': '+value+'; '; //get string with text styles. String looks like: 'font-size: 12px; color: #fff000;' 
            })                
            addTextWithControls(this.id, this.posX, this.posY, this.text, styles);
        });
```

Input data with name 'json' it is a information about text layers. Font size, color, font style etc.
And this variant is **WORKING**!

But if want to call same function addTextWithControls() by this way:

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
           $('#addText').on('click', function(){                
             var id = getMaxTextId();   //get max id before appending             
             addTextWithControls(id, '320', '120', 'Test sample', 'font-size: 25px; color: red;');
           });
        });
```

Text and inputs appends but I occur error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object #`<Object>` has no method 'draggable'

which linked with (this information from console. I can't add a picture because don't have enough reputation):

```
$(function() {                
            $( "div.finishedPic span" ).draggable({ containment: "parent" ,
   Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'draggable'  
                drag: function(){
                    console.log('.');                        
                },
            });
```

And draggable **IS NOT WORKING**. So the main question is: Why the same function addTextWithControls() called by two different places behave differently. Please help me because my brain is melting.

Comment: did  you include teh jquery ui library

Comment: Everything needed are included. Because it working after loading page but dont works after click event.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you haven't included the jQuery UI script.
You can add these to your html:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"</script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Or, maybe, you included it AFTER your script.

Comment: No. Everethig is ok with including order.

Comment: I founded a problem few moment ago.

Comment: But I cant answer for my own question. Because: Users with less than 10 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking. You can answer 3/20/2014 3:18:52 PM. Until then please use comments, or edit your question instead.

Comment: Maybe you can delete it.

Comment: Sure. I turned off it.

Comment: I mean the question. Maybe you delete it?

Comment: Sometimes not obvious problems waste a lot of time. Maybe my question will help somebody.

Answer (score 0):

FFFFUUUUUUUU!!!!!! 
I wasted a plenty of time for this fcking bug. The problem was in ZFDebug bar. I use Zend framework for this project and including of ZFDebug bar sometimes add strange bugs to javascript.

**BE CAREFUL WITH ZFDebug! If something strange is happening in your Zend project, turn off ZFDebug.**